# Facebook Android SDK getting cached access token

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I need to check if access token exists at some point in the APP's lifecycle. How would I retrieve a cached access token in Facebook Android SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you should use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html). What you would do is commit the token to the user's SharedPreference after you recieve it from Facebook, and then you can check it throughout your app whenever you need it.

**Storing the Token**

```
  SharedPreferences sharedPref = yourActivity.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
  editor.putString("user_token", theUsersToken);
  editor.commit();
```

**Retrieving the token.**

```
String token = sharedPref.getString("user_token", "empty");
if(token.equals("empty"))
  //user is not logged in..
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
```

In the latest version of the SDK